# Unable to update attribute value

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to change attribute table columnd value when intersection is found but this is not updating. see comments for details

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()
print layers[0].name()
print layers[1].name()
selections = []
for f in layers[0].getFeatures():
  for a in layers[1].getFeatures():
    if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
      intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())
      print 'polyTwo  '+a['PolyTwo']
      a['PolyTwo'] = 'xyz'#updating value PolyTwo to xyz 
      print 'After polyTwo  '+a['PolyTwo'] #change value is showing here but not in db
      print intersection.exportToWkt()
      selections.append(f.id())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few key code statements:

- You need to start an edit session on the layer you want to update:

  ```
  layers[1].startEditing()
  ```
- Next you will have to grab the field index where to perform the attribute update on and use change attribute method:

  ```
  fieldIndex = layers[1].fieldNameIndex('fieldName')
  layers[1].changeAttributeValue(a.id(),fieldIndex,newValue)
  ```
- Finally, you will have to commit the changes after all attribute updates:

  ```
  layers[1].commitChanges()
  ```

Comment: what is feature.id and field index. i guess feature id is the attribut table id and filed index?

Answer (score 4):

Basically the same as @artwork21, but with less code and more safety overall ;)

```
# Make sure the layer is not in edit state here
with edit(layers[1]):
    for ...
        for a in layers[1].getFeatures():
            a['PolyTwo'] = 'xyz'
            layers[1].updateFeature(a)
```

The code will commit all changes in the end (when the `edit` block is finished) or rollback the changes in case there was an exception to avoid partial results.

Comment: File "E:/QGISSE~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 198, in __enter__
    assert self.layer.startEditing()
AssertionError

Comment: i have got error above error

Comment: I guess the layer was already in edit state before?

Comment: no sir there is nothing edit state before

Comment: Does the comment `layers[1].startEditing()` from the other answer return true?

Comment: other answer wroked from me that is i accept it but you answer looking so simple so i want to try this also and it os not wokring

Comment: You can also combine the two answers and user `udpateFeature` in combination with `startEditing` / `stopEditing`. But it would be nice to know why `edit(layer)` is not working for you, based on your first comment, the `layer.startEditing()` call fails. But if the other answer is working, I wonder why it works there...

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I also faced an error: `assert self.layer.startEditing()
AssertionError` when I tried to delete. But the `startEditing()` is not working too.

Comment: It finally worked when I added the loop on features inside `with edit`.